# android linearlaout layout_width not working as expected

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

What is wrong in this xml ? the two textviews don't seem to occupy same space

```
           <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/detail_address" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:padding="10px"
                android:layout_weight="1">
                <TextView android:id="@+id/address" android:text="Address:"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:textColor="@color/fontonbg"
                    android:gravity="right" android:layout_weight="1" />
                <TextView android:id="@+id/address_details"
                    android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@color/bigfontonbg" android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="16sp" android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/address_btn"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10px" android:gravity="left"
                    android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
                <ImageView android:id="@+id/address_btn" android:src="@drawable/button"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10px" />
            </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

This statment tells Android that the view wants to be just large enough to fit its own internal content, taking its own padding into account. This means that the width will depend on the length of the text on this TextView

Comment: that did the trick, I changed the width to fill parent and it worked :) thanks

Answer (score 2):

When you use android:layout_weight, you should not use `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` but `android:layout_width="0dp"`.

Answer (score -2):

set  `android:orientation="vertical"` in  Linear layout properties

Comment: I want the layout to be horizontal